# empty row in QTreeWidget after item delete

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have created a QTreeWidget with Qt Creator and filled it.

When i delete an item from the tree,an empty line moves down to the end of the tree.
When i then add to the tree, the item adds below the empty line.

How do i get rid of this empty line?

Image: http://picpaste.com/gpa-GNtd84Ev.PNG

```
void Gpa::on_removeButton_clicked()
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);

    item = ui->treeWidget->currentItem();
    QString txt = item->text(0);

   //search vector for item
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        if(vec.at(i)->getCode() == txt)
            break;
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);

    int index = ui->treeWidget->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
    ui->treeWidget->takeTopLevelItem(index);
}
```

Comment: How do you delete the item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are removing a top level item, you should take a look at this method:

```
QTreeWidgetItem * QTreeWidget::takeTopLevelItem ( int index )
```

Otherwise, if you are removing a child you should get a pointer to the top level item (or a child of a top level item) and use:

```
QTreeWidgetItem * QTreeWidgetItem::takeChild ( int index )
```

**EDIT** (after OP has posted his code)

I believe the problem lies here:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);

item = ui->treeWidget->currentItem();
```

You are allocating a new QTreeWidgetItem, and then you assign the item you want to remove to that pointer. So basically, you are creating new empty item and you remove the old one. Try to change your code to:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item;

item = ui->treeWidget->currentItem();
```

Comment: I removed from a top level item. The problem is that after removing, there is an empty row in the table. How do i get rid of this row?

Comment: And did you use takeTopLevelItem method? If yes and the problem still persist, then you should post your code.